# Determine if a URL exists or not?

Tags: java, exception

I have a loop which iterates through a lot of URLs. My problem is that the program is writing out the content of each url in the terminal, and I just want to ignore the broken urls. How do I determine whether a URL is referring to something or not?

Am I forced to make use of the exception FileNotFoundException that is being thrown? Because of that it affects other parts of the program too, I want to ensure that the main while loop directly jumps to the next iteration if the url is broken. The exception is thrown by a method that I am using (within a class that I cannot change), how do I handle that?

Here is my loop (simplified):

```
while(!queue.isEmpty()) {
    URL thisURL = (URL)queue.poll();
    String page = Customurlclass.openURL(thisURL); // return a string containing the page that the url is refering to.
    System.out.println(page);
    // Some other things is also happening here, an I don't want them to happen if the url is broken.
}
```

So the openURL() is catching the FileNotFoundException and there is a lot of things printed in the terminal, I just want to ignore them, how do I do that?

Comment: Please define "valid URL". Does it mean simply looking well formed or that live website returns 200 for GET request?

Comment: A valid URL should return a live website 200.

Answer (score 1):

To verify if your String is valid URL or not, you can use Apache commons-validator [URLValidator class](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-validator/apidocs/org/apache/commons/validator/routines/UrlValidator.html) as below:

```
String[] schemes = {"http","https"}; // DEFAULT schemes = "http", "https", "ftp"
UrlValidator urlValidator = new UrlValidator(schemes);
if (urlValidator.isValid("ftp://foo.bar.com/")) {
   System.out.println("url is valid");
} else {
   System.out.println("url is invalid");
}
```

---

Or even if you like to do it without using the `Apache common-validator` you can have something like below:

```
try {
    URL url = new URL("http://www.yoursite.com/");
    URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
    conn.connect();
} catch (MalformedURLException e) {
    // the URL is not in a valid form
} catch (IOException e) {
    // the connection couldn't be established
}
```

Comment: How do I import the apache class?

Comment: If you are using `maven` then you can look for the dependency, if not you can download the`jar` file and place it in the build path.